# how to move string from position to position in bash (sed, awk)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Please help me:)
How to move string from 4-line to under 1-line in bash (awk, sed)?

Example, i have a file:

```
line1
line2
line3
moveline4
```

result use SED, AWK and other utils:

```
line1
moveline4
line2
line3
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I have answered to your question hereunder, let me know if something is not clear. Hope it helps you! and next time try to respect SO rules.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, in the future I will improve! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**input file**:

```
line1
line2
line3
moveline4
line5
line6
```

**sed solution:**

```
sed -n -e '1p' -e '4p' lines.txt; sed -n -e '2,3p' -e '5,$p' lines.txt
```

**output:**

```
line1
moveline4
line2
line3
line5
line6
```

You can redirect your ouput to a specific file (`>` and `>>`)

```
sed -n -e '1p' -e '4p' lines.txt > new_file.txt; sed -n -e '2,3p' -e '5,$p' lines.txt >> new_file.txt
```

**explanation:**

- `-n` to avoid default printing of lines
- `-e` to pass several commands to `sed`
- `1p` to print the first line
- `4p` to print the 4th line
- `2,3p` to print the 2nd and 3rd line
- `5,$p` to print the 5th line to the last line

**awk solution:**

```
awk 'NR==1||NR==4' lines.txt; awk 'NR>=2 && NR!=4' lines.txt
```

You can redirect your ouput to a specific file (`>` and `>>`)

```
awk 'NR==1||NR==4' lines.txt > new_file.txt; awk 'NR>=2 && NR!=4' lines.txt >> new_file.txt
```

**explanation:**

- `NR==1||NR==4` will make `awk` do its default action for **number record 1** or **4** which is printing (lines `1` and `4`)
- `NR>=2 && NR!=4` for lines `>=2` and `!=4` you print them

**head/tail solution:**

```
head -1 lines.txt; head -4 lines.txt| tail -1; head -3 lines.txt | tail -2; tail -n +5 lines.txt
```

for information about the behavior of head and tail please do `man head` and `man tail`

**perl solution:**

```
perl -ne 'print if 1..1' lines.txt; perl -ne 'print if 4..4' lines.txt; perl -ne 'print if 2..3' lines.txt; perl -ne 'print if 5..6' lines.txt
```

**full bash solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#print the 1st line
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 echo "$line"
 break
done <"$1"

#print the 4th line
x=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 if [ $x -eq 4 ]; then
  echo "$line"
  break
 fi
 x=$((x+1))
done <"$1"

#print all lines except the 1st and the 4th
x=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 if [ $x -ne 1 -a $x -ne 4 ]; then
  echo "$line"
 fi
 x=$((x+1))
done <"$1"
```

you can call the script `./myscript.sh lines.txt` and redirect the output if necessary: `./myscript.sh lines.txt > new_file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed '2{N;h;d};4G;' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `2N`: merges second and third line
- `h`: stores both lines into the hold space
- `d`: deletes both lines
- `4G`: adds the pattern space content after fourth line